# What is the acronym of "SDL" in SDL Tridion

Tags: 2011

I would like to know the acronym of "SDL" in SDL Tridion. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Just to throw in there that some dictionaries define 'Acronym' to mean a word in it's original sense, 'SDL' (some would argue) is actually an 'Initialism': http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/abbreviations/abbreviations-acronyms-and-initialisms-revisited/ Right back to trolling the work skype group :)

Comment: Re - acronym versus abbreviation: firstly, the A in TLA can stand for either. Strictly an acronym forms a "name" (that's the 'nym' part), so if you spell the letters out (ess-dee-ell), I'd say it was an abbreviation rather than an acronym.

Comment: WoW. Is this question really belongs here and number of up votes ?  http://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic . It seems to be community choice rather than following the rules.. wonder..

Comment: I agree with you that this question doesn't fit here, but the number of votes suggests it is considered valuable information. I'm fine with moving this question to the META discussion instead.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

SDL is the name of the company that develops, maintains and sells SDL Tridion.

SDL (http://www.sdl.com) is a publicly traded company with roots in the early 90s (founded in 1992) with a strong focus on Global Information Management, and especially professional translation of Software and Documentation.

SDL is a TLA (Three Letter Acronym) for "Software and Documentation Localization".

Tridion was a privately funded company based in Amsterdam, and was acquired by SDL in April 2007.

Comment: Are you sure it is not "Software and Documentation Localization"? so localization of software and documentation, not documentation and localization of software?

Comment: That's probably it. Always have problems placing the and.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, SDL is not an acronym. It is a question I get a lot and sometimes people says "what do you mean it is not an acronym?"

Edit:

Apparently it is an acronym. Check Nuno's answer out.

Comment: You should know it _is_ an acronym. :)

Comment: I know, but I thought it wasn't. What does TLA stand for? Is it an acronym too?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-letter_acronym