# What does the acronym or initialism RWS refer to?

Tags: sdl-tridion

What does it mean, or how do you pronounce it?

Answer (score 0):

Just like [SDL](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/what-is-the-acronym-of-sdl-in-sdl-tridion), RWS is indeed an initialism. You can read some of the history here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RWS_Group

RWS, which in the Netherlands also stands for the government entity responsible for keeping our feet dry, stands for Randall Woolcott Services.

You read it as Arr-DoubleU-Ess, I guess.